# How to determine storage type (SAN/NAS/local disk) remotely, using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, storage, nas, san

I have to collect the attached storage types of each server in our environment:  Several hundreds of W2K3/W2K8 servers.

A script would be very useful to determine if the attached storage is `SAN / SAN mirrored / NAS / local` or combination of these. The problem is that I haven't really found any good solution.

I was thinking about a script, and the best I could figure out would do something like the following:

- If the server uses `SAN`, Veritas Storage Foundation is always installed, so I would search for it with gwmi win32_product. This is really slow, and this doesn't provide the information if the storage is SAN, or SAN mirrored.
- If the attached storage is `NAS`, there must be an ISCSI target ip, and I would search for that somehow.

I really don't think these methods are acceptable though. Could you please help me find a better way to determine the attached storage types somehow?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have PS2.0 on the W2k3 servers?

Comment: use diskpart ? ex diskpart, select disk 1 , detail disk : type will be iSCSI for SAN disk

Comment: Have you worked out how to do this *locally*? (Ie. is this a remoting question or a system information question?)

Comment: This must be a system information question since he explains how he first plan it(searching for veritas storage foundation etc.) and then ask for improved methods to detect storage type.

Answer (score 2):

I found an article about accessing the VDS service in powershell. [Getting More Information About You Cluster LUN’s](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylorb/archive/2010/07/01/getting-more-information-about-you-cluster-lun-s-part-3-of-3.aspx)

Massaged the code a bit to get type. Works even on 2003.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Storage.Vds") | Out-Null
$oVdsServiceLoader = New-Object Microsoft.Storage.Vds.ServiceLoader
$oVdsService = $oVdsServiceLoader.LoadService($null) 
$oVdsService.WaitForServiceReady() 
$oVdsService.Reenumerate() 
$cDisks = ($oVdsService.Providers |% {$_.Packs}) |% {$_.Disks}
$cPacks = $oVdsService.Providers |% {$_.Packs}

foreach($oPack in $cPacks)
{
    If($oPack.Status -eq "Online")
    {
        foreach($oDisk in $oPack.Disks)
        {
            Write-Host "$($oDisk.FriendlyName) ( $($oDisk.BusType) )"
        }


        foreach($oVolume in $oPack.Volumes)
        {
            Write-Host "`t$($oVolume.AccessPaths) ( $($oVolume.Label) )"
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably find the info in one of the following WMI classes:

Win32_LogicalDisk
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx

Win32_Volume
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394515(v=vs.85).aspx

Win32_DiskDrive
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx

Then... do something like:

```
Get-AdComputer Server* | Foreach-Object { Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $_.Name }
```